# Increase lifetime of homemade chocolates

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, chocolate

I recently stated making my own chocolates. (No bars, but filled chocolates and pralines) 
I also make the filling myself. Now I have a question about the lifetime of this chocolates. On different sites I read that the lifetime is about 2-3 weeks when keeping them on room temperature. And maybe only 2-3 days for some kind of pralines.

Because I make the filling myself, I can not really make less then around 15/20 chocolates at the same time, with the same filling (or I would just waste a lot of chocolate and filling). I would really like to give some people a box of chocolates as a present, with different flavours, which means I make lots and lots of chocolates. Also when I make them for myself I do enjoy a couple of them, but I don't have to eat so many chocolates in such small amount of time.

So does someone ha some tips about: 
-Increasing the life time of the chocolates
For example: different way to store them.

Also maybe someone has a good idea like: If I would made different kinds of filling, can I freeze this, and only use a little of each when I want to use them? Does this influence the flavor?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 6):

If you freeze the chocolate, it'll likely "bloom" (some of the cocoa butter will separate out, leaving white spots). This is an entirely aesthetic problem; they'll be perfectly safe to eat, and it doesn't affect the flavor much. So, you may want to try this for your personal treats.

The filling may or may not freeze well, depends on what the filling is. First, if its a fairly concentrated sugar syrup, then it may not freeze (because the freezer isn't cold enough, it'll just get really thick). But it'll last much longer. Most fillings are also perfectly happy in the fridge, and will last longer that way too (but not as long as in the freezer).

Other fillings may suffer texture changes. E.g., freezing may separate any emulsion.

You probably won't have issues with water escaping, as your fillings should all be low-water anyway.

As with anything in the freezer, tight moisture and air impermeable packaging will work best.